# Angular 2 testing Router with Jasmine and Karma

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-runner, angular2-testing, angular2-router

I am having issues writing a stub for router.navigate in angular 2. I currently have the below stub written. Which is what shows up in the angular docs.

```
@Injectable
export class RouterStub {
    navigate(commands: any[], extras?: NavigationExtras) { }
```

However, when I use this stub I get the following error.

```
TypeError: this.router.navigate is not a function
```

And my usage of navigate is as follows.

```
let summaryLink = ['/summary', this.client.id, this.client.lastName];
this.router.navigate(summaryLink);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Just an update... I was able to get this test working using a non TestBed method that I found referenced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37356565/angular2-rc-1-inject-router-into-unit-test). However, if anyone is able to figure out how I can get this test working with the TestBed method I would appreciate the help. 
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You have to bootstrap your tests including the Router module. This is pretty the same like bootstrapping the application:

```
const IMPORTS: any[] = [
    BrowserModule,
    ...
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
];

beforeEach(async(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: IMPORTS,
    declarations: DECLARATIONS
    providers: PROVIDERS
  }).compileComponents();
}));
```

Then, you can obtain the reference to the router.

```
 beforeEach(() => {
  router = TestBed.get(Router);
  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(YourComponent);
  component = fixture.componentInstance;
  element = fixture.nativeElement;
});
```

Test for state (requires dependencies since the components get rendered and so on):

```
it('routes to the dummy component', fakeAsync(() => {
  tick(1000);
  fixture.detectChanges();

  router.navigate(['dummy']);

  tick(1000);
  fixture.detectChanges();

  expect(router.isActive('/dummy', true)).toBe(true);
}));
```

Test for communication (does not route; we just have to verify whether the navigation really happened):

```
it('routes to the dummy component', fakeAsync(() => {
  spyOn(router, 'navigate').and.callFake(() => {});
  tick(1000);
  fixture.detectChanges();

  router.navigate(['dummy']);

  tick(1000);
  fixture.detectChanges();

  expect(router.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith(['dummy']);
}));
```

In a real test, you aren't going to test the navigate() method. In fact, you are going to test some kind of the user behaviour, e.g. click:

In the component (in this case YourComponent):

```
onClick() {
    this.router.navigate(['dummy']);
}
```

In the test (replace navigate() by a click trigger):

```
element.querySelector('button').click();
```